# How to remove inherited/auto row gaps generated while using gridbox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am not able to remove inherited/auto row gaps generated while using gridbox. When I try to remove the gap by reducing it to negative, the whole column gap just disappears.

And also I would like to solve the overflowing problem caused when trying to make the site responsive.

I am a beginner.

```js
let homeEl = document.getElementById("home-el")
let guestEl = document.getElementById("guest-el")
let homeRun = 0
let guestRun = 0

function increment1() {
  homeRun += 1
  homeEl.textContent = homeRun
}

function increment2() {
  homeRun = homeRun + 2
  homeEl.textContent = homeRun
}

function increment3() {
  homeRun = homeRun + 3
  homeEl.textContent = homeRun
}

function increment1() {
  guestRun += 1
  guestEl.textContent = guestRun
}

function increment2() {
  guestRun += 2
  guestEl.textContent = guestRun
}

function increment3() {
  guestRun += 3
  guestEl.textContent = guestRun
}
```

```css
* {
  /* max-width: 500px; */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.big {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #1B244A;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  gap: 0 12rem;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.title-home {
  font-family: 'Verdana';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 8vh;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 9vw;
}

.title-guest {
  font-family: 'Verdana';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 8vh;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 9vw;
}

.homeScore {
  background-color: black;
  height: 20vh;
  width: 10vw;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  display: grid;
  align-content: center;
  font-family: 'Cursed Timer ULiL';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 6rem;
  color: #F94F6D;
}

.guestScore {
  background-color: black;
  height: 20vh;
  width: 10vw;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  display: grid;
  align-content: center;
  font-family: 'Cursed Timer ULiL';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 6rem;
  color: #F94F6D;
}

.increment {
  background-color: #1B244A;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 10vw;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  gap: 0 0.5rem;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'Cursed Timer ULiL';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #9AABD8;
}

.increaseBy1 {
  border: 3px solid #9AABD8;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 4.5vh;
  width: 1.6vw;
}

.increaseBy2 {
  border: 3px solid #9AABD8;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 4.5vh;
  width: 1.6vw;
}

.increaseBy3 {
  border: 3px solid #9AABD8;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 4.5vh;
  width: 1.6vw;
}

#increase-btn {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-family: 'Cursed Timer ULiL';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: #9AABD8;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Basketball Score Card</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="big">

    <div class="title-home"> HOME</div>
    <div class="title-guest">GUEST</div>
    <div class="homeScore">
      <p id="home-el">0</p>
    </div>
    <div class="guestScore" id="guest-el">
      <p id="guest-el">0</p>
    </div>
    <div class="increment">
      <div class="increaseBy1">
        <button id="increase-btn" type="button" onclick="increment1()">+1</button>
      </div>
      <div class="increaseBy2">
        <button id="increase-btn" type="button" onclick="increment2()">+2</button>
      </div>
      <div class="increaseBy3">
        <button id="increase-btn" type="button" onclick="increment3()">+3</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="increment">
      <div class="increaseBy1">
        <button type="button" id="increase-btn" onclick="increment1()">+1</button>
      </div>
      <div class="increaseBy2">
        <button type="button" id="increase-btn" onclick="increment2()">+2</button>
      </div>
      <div class="increaseBy3">
        <button type="button" id="increase-btn" onclick="increment3()">+3</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]